# Coldfusion threads slow.. what could be causing it..?

Tags: coldfusion

Lately I have been receiving error messages from my CF server via email stating that:

> "ColdFusion: Unresponsive Server Alert active"
>
> 10 or more threads are busy for more than 60 seconds.
>
> - Total Running requests - 28
> - Total Queued requests - 0
> - Template Running requests - 28
> - Template Queued requests - 0
> - Flash Remoting Running requests - 0
> - Flash Remoting Queued requests - 0
> - CFC method Running requests - 0
> - CFC method Queued requests - 0
> - Web Service Running requests - 0
> - Web Service Queued requests - 0

Would the reason be that the use of a `cfthread` is taking a long time? When processing on our sites, they sometimes have to consume a lot of data from external services. Or could it possibly be due to `cfthread` tasks overlapping each other ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your threads should not overlap each other, but if your code is creating a lot of cftreads they could be fighting for resources. If your server is underpowered, you would have threads that have to queue up and wait for their turn. If that's the case, you have two options: beef up your server, or try to optimize your code (if possible) to reduce the number of competing threads. Also, if you are doing database work, you could look at optimizing your queries and tables (indexes, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Check your Coldfusion administrator (under Request Tuning) which allows you to increase the number of threads available, how deep to queue them up when your requests surpass those available, as well as how long to let a thread run before killing it.

If you limit yourself to 10 (the default I think) and 10 people all hit a page that occupy your available threads, then CF will queue up further requests. If your queue passes it's limit, no new requests are taken (or is it killed?). Those threads that run over 60 seconds are killed to make those resources available to the next person.

You really need to find what is taking over 60 seconds to complete and optimize it.  If you cannot, then you'll have to increase your allowance for more threads (this will require more memory) or at least allow your queue to deepen (which will frustrate your users since they won't get a response until their thread get's a chance to execute).